# MacOS Admin User not having write access

Tags: macos, permissions, file-access

As an Admin user shown in User & Groups in the settings of my MacBook, when I try to write things to any files using applications, for example saving edits on a file in my user folder with VSCode, I am prompted to input my password to save. And with terminal, I have to add sudo on applications, and scripts will almost always get EACCESS error.

I have turned off csrutil but I am still having the issue.

So how do I fix it so that I don't need to input password everytime in an application nor using sudo on every line in terminal, without logging in as root but simply as admin user?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up fixing it by wiping the disk and reinstalling macOS, still could not find the reason for this though.

Make sure you actually wipe the disk before reinstalling macOS as I tried reinstalling without wiping and it didn't work.